# gitlab 8.2.0 git not working

Tags: linux, git, ubuntu, gitlab

I installed gitlab 8.2.0 from source and followed the instructions on https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/blob/master/doc/install/installation.

When I run the checks with

```
sudo -u git -H bundle exec rake gitlab:check RAILS_ENV=production
```

I get the following error:

```
Running /home/git/gitlab-shell/bin/check
Check GitLab API access: FAILED. code: 301
gitlab-shell self-check failed
Try fixing it:
  Make sure GitLab is running;
  Check the gitlab-shell configuration file:
  sudo -u git -H editor /home/git/gitlab-shell/config.yml
  Please fix the error above and rerun the checks.

Checking GitLab Shell ... Finished
```

Here is my config.yml file from /home/git/gitlab-shell:

```
user: git
gitlab_url: "http://www.example.com/gitlab"
http_settings:
  #ca_path: /etc/ssl/certs
  self_signed_cert: true
repos_path: "/home/git/repositories/"
auth_file: "/home/git/.ssh/authorized_keys"
redis:
  bin: "/usr/bin/redis-cli"
  namespace: resque:gitlab
  socket: "/var/run/redis/redis.sock"
log_level: INFO
audit_usernames: false
```

Note that I am using the relative URL feature to run gitlab on www.example.com/gitlab. Also the server is behind a reverse proxy that terminates https to http if this should be of any relevance for this problem.

I also cant' push or pull any repositories. When I try to I get the following error:

```
git pull https://www.example.com/gitlab/test/testproject.git
Username for 'https://www.example.com': test
Password for 'https://test@www.example.com':
fatal: Couldn't find remote ref HEAD
Unexpected end of command stream
```

I also can't add any files to any project via the webUI. If I try to do so I get the following error

```
Commit was rejected by pre-receive hook
```

The log for this from production.log looks as follows:

```
Sarted POST "/gitlab/test/testprojekt/create/master" for 147.86.8.115 at             2015-11-26 15:24:43 +0100
Processing by Projects::BlobController#create as JSON
Parameters: {"new_branch"=>"master", "create_merge_request"=>"1",  "commit_message"=>"test", "file"=># <ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x007f776230faf8 @tempfile=# <Tempfile:/tmp/RackMultipart20151126-7584-308za1>,  @original_filename="test2.txt", @content_type="text/plain", @headers="Content-  Disposition: form-data; name=\"file\"; filename=\"test2.txt\"\r\nContent-Type:  text/plain\r\n">, "namespace_id"=>"test", "project_id"=>"testprojekt",  "id"=>"master"}
Completed 200 OK in 628ms (Views: 0.3ms | ActiveRecord: 3.3ms)
Started GET "/gitlab/test/testprojekt/new/master" for 147.86.8.115 at 2015-11-26 15:24:44 +0100
Processing by Projects::BlobController#new as HTML
Parameters: {"namespace_id"=>"test", "project_id"=>"testprojekt", "id"=>"master"}
Completed 200 OK in 85ms (Views: 49.6ms | ActiveRecord: 6.0ms)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you could try switching  `gitlab_url: "http://www.example.com/gitlab"` to https -> `gitlab_url: "https://www.example.com/gitlab"`

Not sure if its a complete fix but its a recomendations.

EDIT: 
config.yml line 4 should look like

```
ca_path: "/etc/ssl/certs"
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, that did unfortunately not solve my problem.

Comment: Ok, I would still keep the HTTPS and when I get a little more time I will look at it once again.